# replace all url from html file with regex php

Tags: php

i want to save external html file using php 
how to search and replace all url with regex using php

```
href="/web/***/http://blog.domain.com/site/styles-site.css"
```

where *** is code dynamic not known

replace to

```
href="site/styles-site.css"
```

mycode:

```
$html=$url;
 $content = file_get_contents($html);


$newhtml = preg_replace( 'web/-[^-.]*\./' , '.' , $content);
file_put_contents('post1.html', $newhtml);
```

Comment: Will you give some more examples of urls?

Comment: yes ,like href="/web/***/http://blog.domain.com/site/page2.html" ,href="/web/***/http://blog.domain.com/site/hgdhddkdkd.jpg"